# VTK: Interact with Actor/Assembly, but without having to click directly on it

Tags: python, vtk

In my application I build a vtkAssembly Object and I can interact with it by using a custom InteractorStyle that expands the vtkInteractorStyleTrackballActor. I add the Interactor to the render window and set my custom style. I can rotate, scale and move the object, everything works as intended.

Because this is the only object in the render window, I'd like to allow the user to control the object from anywhere. More specifically: The user doesn't have to place the mouse exactly over the object in order to rotate, scale, etc.

I already have an Observer that triggers when the user clicks on the render window and not only the object itself, but how can I trigger the corresponding rotation of the object?

This is my custom vtkInteractorStyle class:

```
class SynchronousInteractorStyle(vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballActor):

    button_active = False

    def __init__(self, process, parent=None):
        self.process = process
        self.AddObserver("LeftButtonPressEvent", self.left_button_press_event)
        self.AddObserver("LeftButtonReleaseEvent", self.left_button_release_event)
        self.AddObserver("MiddleButtonPressEvent", self.middle_button_press_event)
        self.AddObserver("MiddleButtonReleaseEvent", self.middle_button_release_event)
        self.AddObserver("RightButtonPressEvent", self.right_button_press_event)
        self.AddObserver("RightButtonReleaseEvent", self.right_button_release_event)

    def left_button_press_event(self, obj, event):
        print("I'm triggered!")
        self.button_active = True
        self.OnLeftButtonDown()
        return

    def left_button_release_event(self, obj, event):
        self.button_active = False
        self.OnLeftButtonUp()
        return

    def middle_button_press_event(self, obj, event):
        self.button_active = True
        self.OnMiddleButtonDown()
        return

    def middle_button_release_event(self, obj, event):
        self.button_active = False
        self.OnMiddleButtonUp()
        return

    def right_button_press_event(self, obj, event):
        self.button_active = True
        self.OnRightButtonDown()
        return

    def right_button_release_event(self, obj, event):
        self.button_active = False
        self.OnRightButtonUp()
        return
```

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:
I think I found a possible way to get what I want to achieve.
There is the possibility to override the OnLeftButtonDown(interactor) method, but I can't figure out what functions I have to call in order to start, for example, a rotation.

This is a example of my override attempt, but interactor delivers a vtkInteractorStyleTrackballActor object and calling StartRotation() doesn't do anything.

```
def OnLeftButtonDown(interactor):
    print(interactor)
    interactor.StartRotate()
    return
```